# C# Question about Data Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the buttons populated in a DataGrid, now I want them to show on the right of the data not the default position (left). How can I achieve this?

Thank you

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myDataGrid"
BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" 
GridLines="None">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

PS: I am binding the data to an array

```
  myDataGrid.DataSource = vals;
  myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a column for the array of string before the button column like this

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="someLabelId" runat="server" 
                                              Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>

   <asp:TemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

and set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` for the `DataGrid`

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```

Comment: This was it, thank you very much. One last question how can code against the button?

Comment: You can either introduce `OnClick` attribute with the `Click` event handler or use the `OnCommand` attribute and define the `Command` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

use ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" as defined at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemstyle.aspx

try:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the alignment of the column. He/she wants autogenerated columns first and then the button column. By default, the button column comes up to the left and all the auto generated columns to the right.

Comment: hmm.. so it turns out that wasnt what he wanted - your accepted solution didnt use autogen'd columns unless I missed something? This was a simple case of column order? I guess I read too much into it : )